# Output device gone after upgrading to El Capitan

Tags: audio, macos

I have been using [E-MU 0404](http://www.creative.com/emu/products/product.aspx?pid=15185) for sound output - it's connected to my iMac by USB and outputs sound from my computer to speakers. After upgrading to OS X 10.11, El Capitan, the E-MU 0404 is gone from the list of output devices.

There is a [USB audio control panel application](http://support.creative.com/downloads/download.aspx?nDownloadId=12115), provided by Creative, which used to detect the device and do some basic configuration, but now it does not detect anything.

Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

From [Creative's Forum](http://forums.creative.com/showthread.php?t=729688):

> Dear E-MU customers,
>
> All E-MU enquiries are now being managed by a dedicated E-MU Team
>   which took effect on 5 May 2014.
>
> If you need their assistance about El Capitan support, you may contact
>   the team directly at :
>
> Technical support enquiries -> support@emu.com
>
> Other enquiries -> enquiry@emu.com